# How To Register Generic Repository With SimpleIOC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, repository-pattern

How can I register generic Repository with SimpleIOC?

```
  public interface IRepository<T>
  {

  }

  public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
  {

  }

  SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRepository, Repository>(); //Doesn't work, throws error


 Error  1   Using the generic type 'AdminApp.Repository.IRepository<TModel>' requires 1 type arguments  C:\Application Development\AdminApp\AdminApp.Desktop\ViewModel\ViewModelLocator.cs  55  44  AdminApp.Desktop
```

I Also tried:

```
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRepository<>, Repository<>>(); //Doesn't work either
     Error  1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement   C:\Application Development\AdminApp\AdminApp.Desktop\ViewModel\ViewModelLocator.cs  55  17  AdminApp.Desktop
```

Comment: "Throws error". Shall we guess the error? Surely its descriptive ..

Comment: Ok I added the errors. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc` ([source code](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras%20%28NET35%29/Ioc/SimpleIoc.cs)) supports **open generic** implementations. You would need to create closed implementations and register each of them separately:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class { }

public class A { }
public class B { }

public class RepositoryA : IRepository<A> { }
public class RepositoryB : IRepository<B> { }

SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRepository<A>, RepositoryA>();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRepository<B>, RepositoryB>();
```

I suggest you consider moving to a more mature library such as [SimpleInjector](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector) which has extensive support for generics.

The code for SimpleInjector would be as simple as:

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

Comment: Yea thats what I wound up doing. Thanks.